# How to route RabbitMQ messages to RAM node instead of directly storing them on Disk node

Tags: rabbitmq, ram, drive

RabbitMQ by default stores the messages Disk node. Is there any option to route the messages to RAM node instead of directly storing them on the disk node?

It is bit urgent. Please suggest me.

Regards,
Rambabu

Answer (score 0):

You can't. RabbitMQ must at least have one disk node.

> A cluster must always have at least one disk node.

See [rabbitmqctl man](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html)